# Problem with java FTP upload

Tags: java, xml, upload, ftp, network-programming

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException{
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        client.connect("ftp.someserver.co.uk",21);
        boolean login = client.login("webmaster@someserver.co.uk",
                "mypassword");


        String filename = "C:/Users/NAVEEN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/engine_3018683681918436492.xml";
        fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
        if(client.storeFile("myfile.xml", fis)){
            System.out.println("yes");
        }else{
            System.out.println("no");

        }
        client.logout();
        fis.close();
    }
```

This code is uploading the file as I wanted, but not uploading all the contents of it. Some of the files content are not there!

## EDIT -1

ok now I created a static file and tries uploading it, but its the same situation again.

Comment: Try doing `fis.close()` and then `client.logout()`

Comment: May be issue with file names `~` and other spaces and other characters

Comment: So what's being printed out -- yes or no?  Is it not completing successfully or is it claiming it is completing successfully but not uploading the whole file?

Comment: You should also have a try { } finally { } block for closing the FileInputStream and FTPClient. If an exception is thrown during the operation then you can orphan the connection until it is timed out.

Comment: well, its printing yes, but some of the file contents are not getting there to the uploaded file.

Comment: @Ryan, could you tell me how to implement that try{} finally thing please.

Comment: @Shaunak the file size is approx, 3 kb

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how the file you are trying to upload is getting generated. But looks like it is a temp file. Are you sure it is not being deleted/overwritten while being read from java? Why don't you just keep a static file on desktop and try uploading it for trial.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might need completePendingCommand.  Per the example in there, you can "push" the data yourself by getting the output stream and handling the byte copy yourself.

[http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#completePendingCommand()](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#completePendingCommand%28%29)

Comment: @mad_programmer, did you not click the link that Bill posted? There's an example there that shows exactly how to use it.

Comment: @mad_programmer Explain what "not working" means, still have the same problem or do you get an error message? Are you sure the content of the file is OK?